# Topological difference of $[0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I am taking my first course in topology, and I have just learned about subspaces.
For a set $X$ we defined the subspace $E$ as follows:
if
$(X, \mathcal{T})$
is a topological space,
$E \subseteq X$, and
$\mathcal{T}_E := \{ V \cap E : V \in \mathcal{T} \} $.

1. If I look at $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $[0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by the base $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{a<b \in\Bbb R} (a,b)$, then the subspace $[0,1)$ is an open set because I can demonstrate it as an intersection of an open set in $X$ and the interval itself. For example, we take $V = (-1,1)$.

But, if I look at $X= \mathbb{R}$, then $[0,1)$ is not an open set, with the topology mentioned above. What happens there? Why is it not open, nor closed if I look at the interval as a subset, but it is open as a subspace? What am I missing?

2. Another thing, if I take $X = [a,b)$, with the topology generated by the base $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{a<x<y<b}(x,y)$, does $X$ remain an open set since by definition $X \in \mathcal{T}$? What about intervals of the form $[c,d) \subseteq [a,b)$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, then in (1) your set $\mathcal B$ is not a base for a topology on $[0,1)$. This set $\mathcal B$ consists of subsets of $X$, not subsets of $[0,1)$. Are you somehow implicitly intersecting each $(a,b)$ with $[0,1)$?

Comment: In (1), $\mathcal B$ is a base for the usual topology $\mathcal T$ on $X=\Bbb R$, and yes, $E:=[0,1)\in\mathcal T_E$, as is always the case for a subspace topology. And yes, $E\notin\mathcal T$. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you keep saying "open" instead of "open in this topology" or "open as a subset of this space". You have two different topological spaces that share some subsets, so you need to specify, because "open" becomes a relative term when you have more than one topology.

Comment: As for (2), neither your $\mathcal B$ (like in 1, your notation is again incorrect, I suppose you mean the set of unions of intervals of my $\mathcal B'$) nor my prefered $\mathcal B':=\{(x,y)\mid a<x<y<b\}$ is  a [*base*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for a topology on $X=[a,b)$ because $X$ is not a union of intervals $(x,y)$ such that $a<x<y<b$. Both are however [*subbases*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) generating the same topology $\mathcal T_{[a,b)}$ (the one you defined before). And an interval $[c,d)\subseteq[a,b)$ belongs to that topology iff $c=a$.

Comment: "What am I missing?" You are not missing anything. You made correct observation. And the observation is: being open or closed is not a property of space, it is always relative to some other space. The same subset will be open/closed in one space, but not in another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need to be a bit more careful in your use of the terms that are new to you.

For instance, if you have multiple "universal" sets, or a single set with more than one topology laying around, the description "is an open set" is dangerous. You should be careful to say "$A$ is an open subset **of a particular topological space**".

Some basic facts are:

- A topological space is a set along with a distinguished collection of **subsets**, the open subsets of that space.
- If $B$ is a subset of a topological space, we can create a new topological space by giving $B$ the subspace topology that you correctly described.

Here's where you ran into trouble:

- "then the subspace $[0,1)$ is an open set":

First, a subspace is a new topological space, it is not an open or non-open subset in some other topology.

Second, what you want to say is "$[0,1)$ is an open subset of the space $[0,1)$ (when it is given the subspace topology)".

Also, "$[0,1)$ is *not* an open subset of the topological space $\mathbb R$" is a valid and true statement.

Hopefully with those three points established you can also see that "... it is open as a subspace ..." isn't a proper use of terminology either.

Possibly what's underlying this all is that you're thinking of "being open" as an inherent property of a set. "Being an open subset of" involves two things, the set, and the overall topological space. If a set is a subset of two larger topological spaces, it's possible for it to be an open subset of one, but not of the other.

For your question number 2, maybe it's enough to give an example? If you give $[0,4)$ the topology generated by the collection you give, it'll have the same topology as the subspace topology it inherits from $\mathbb R$. (Although that's a fact that has to be proved; it's not just immediately obvious.) Also, $[0,1)$ *is* an open subset of that space, while $[1,2)$ *is not* an open subset of it. (Again, this requires a little bit of proof.)

And, finally, your notation for bases is a bit off. $\bigcup_{a<b \in\Bbb R} (a,b)$ is a union of a bunch of intervals, and is actually just equal to $\mathbb R$. You should write $\mathcal{B} = \{(a,b) \mid a<b \in\Bbb R\}$.